# Dropdown CSS Selector in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors

I have the following page:
http://live.guru99.com/index.php/mobile.html.
I need to click Sort By "name" on the dropdown list in Selenium, trying to do this with this code:

```
public void f() {

  verifyTitle(baseUrl, "Home page");
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".level0 ")).click();
  verifyTitle(driver.getCurrentUrl(), "Mobile");

  Select dd = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[title=Sort By][css=1]")));
  dd.selectByVisibleText("Name");

}
```

What's wrong with this code? Are quotation marks in right place?

Comment: You need to add single quotes around 'Sort By'? What is "css=1" do? There are 2 similar dropdowns on the page, which one you are trying to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following code:

```
Select dd = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[title='Sort By']")));
dd.selectByVisibleText("Name");
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: @mtmx, if my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please. Thanks.